# ASP.NET MVC SQL

Tags: sql, asp.net-mvc

I have the following code:

```
public IList<ProductionRuns> List()
        {
            var Shows3Months = (from s in _db.ProductionRuns
                                where s.startDate <= DATEADD(month, 3, GETDATE()) and s.endDate > = GETDATE() select s);

            return Shows3Months.ToList();
        }
```

The idea is that it will show a list of productions for the next 3 months so it compares against the production start date and end date with the current date. Can anyone help me fix the SQL statement? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not SQL, that's a LINQ comprehension expression: I think you have your languages confused.

Either stay in C# and your model, or execute SQL on the database.

In C# (with some guessing to fill in the model) I think your expression needs to be something like:

```
var d1 = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);

from s in _db.ProductionRuns
where s.startDate <= d1 && s.endDate >= DateTime.Today
select s
```

EDIT: Pre-calculate date so LINQ to SQL doesn't try and translate it to SQL.

Comment: This will not work as AddMonth is not supported by linq to sql

Comment: @archil OK, so just need to pre-calculate.

Answer (score 3):

```
public IList<ProductionRuns> List()
        {
            DateTime startDate = DateTime.Today.AddMonths(-3);
            DateTime endDate = DateTime.Today;

            var Shows3Months = (from s in _db.ProductionRuns
                                where s.startDate <= startDate and s.endDate >= endDate select s);

            return Shows3Months.ToList();
        }
```